# Do not clear input placeholder when user clicks the input

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, input, placeholder

Is there a way to prevent IE to clear the input placeholder just when a user hits the input field? I would like to have the same behavior like for example Chrome.

When we set a placeholder and hit the input in chrome, the placeholder text doesn't disappear directly, just when the user starts to type in something.

I am wondering how to create the exactly same behavior for IE, CSS, JS is allowed!

Thanks in advance.
Nick

Comment: You can build your own placeholder polyfill ....

Comment: Allow browsers their differences. It shouldn't matter. (If it does matter, then your placeholder text should probably be in a `<label>` instead).

Comment: You can also put label in position fixed with greater Zindex and then the user foes keydown - you can remove this label.